# how to connect roadrunner using imap_open()

Tags: php, pop3

I tried all the below code ,but it does not connect Roadrunner .please anyone help me...i want a correct code for connect roadrunner using imap_open()..

```
<?php
$imap = imap_open("{pop-server.kc.rr.com:995/pop3/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX", "spacemanabove@kc.rr.com","aboveall")or die("can't connect: " . imap_last_error());
?>

<?php
$imap = imap_open("{pop-server.kc.rr.com:110/pop3/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX", "spacemanabove@kc.rr.com","aboveall")or die("can't connect: " . imap_last_error());
?>

<?php
$imap = imap_open("{pop-server.kc.rr.com:110/pop3}INBOX", "spacemanabove@kc.rr.com","aboveall")or die("can't connect: " . imap_last_error());
?>

<?php
$imap = imap_open("{pop-server.kc.rr.com:110/pop3/notls}INBOX", "spacemanabove@kc.rr.com","aboveall")or die("can't connect: " . imap_last_error());
?>

<?php
$imap = imap_open("{pop-server.kc.rr.com:110/notls}INBOX", "spacemanabove@kc.rr.com","aboveall")or die("can't connect: " . imap_last_error());
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use the following server path

```
<?php
$imap = imap_open("{pop-server.kc.rr.com}", "spacemanabove@kc.rr.com","aboveall")or die("can't connect: " . imap_last_error());
?>
```